# React. Display one value send another to the server

Tags: reactjs, select, server, react-hooks, dropdown

Having a ****Select Component**** that receives an array of currencies through the options variable, the user is able to see the value data inside (e.g. US Dollar, Euro) and choose one of them.

At this moment, inside the payload is being sent the whole object when selecting one of the options followed by a server error. In order to validate the value, the server won't accept anything else but a currency code string "USD". So what can I do in order to send the variable value?

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!

```
const options = [
    {
        value: 'US Dollar',
        code: 'USD'
    },
    {
        value: 'Euro',
        code: 'EUR'
    },
    {
        value: 'Japanese yen',
        code: 'JPY'
    }
];

const App = () => {
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');

    return (
        <>
            <Select
                label="Currency"
                options={options}
                onChange={setCurrency}
                value={currency}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the Select Component type ? Do you use any UI framework ?

Comment: I haven't used an UI framework, the component is made from scratch from a text input; fired by onClick it expands and shows a <ul> list

Comment: Ok..so can we have a full detailed example ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
onChange={e=>setCurrency(e.target.value)}
```

or

```
onChange={e=>setCurrency(e.target.value.code)}
```